# Why the join is not working without group by statement

Tags: mysql, sql

If I remove the `group by` statement, then it is showing an error.

```
SELECT COMPANY.COMPANY_CODE,
       company.founder,
       count(distinct lm.lead_manager_code),
       count(distinct sm.senior_manager_code),
       count(distinct m.manager_code),
       count(distinct e.employee_code)
from Company 
join Lead_Manager as lm on Company.company_code = lm.company_code
join Senior_Manager as sm on Company.company_code = sm.company_code
join Manager as m on Company.company_code = m.company_code
join Employee as e on Company.company_code = e.company_code
GROUP BY Company.COMPANY_CODE, Company.FOUNDER
ORDER BY Company.COMPANY_CODE ASC
```

Comment: You use aggregate functions - hence GROUP BY clause presence is compulsory.

Comment: What join are you referring to , there are 4 in the query. And please publish the error message in full.

Comment: MySQL <> SQL server - please correct your tags.

Comment: If you are getting an error, post the error. But also you need to provide a [mre] with sample data and desired results, because removing the `group by` doesn't make any sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you are using an aggregate function so you need to group

`select count(amount) from Orders group by customer_id`

Orders
order_id    item    amount  customer_id
1   Keyboard        400            4
2   Mouse           300            4
3   Monitor       12000            3
4   Keyboard        400            1
5   Mousepad        250            2

Now using group by on customer_id so we have id 4 so need to check the count of 4 id with group by

Comment: Note that as long as only aggregate function are in the SELECT clause, no GROUP BY is needed. It's when you mix aggregate function with regular column expressions, a GROUP BY is required.